# Splitting lines by polygons in QGIS

Tags: qgis, polygon, line, geoprocessing, splitting

I have a river network (lines) and a `.shp` with states (polygon). I would like to split the lines at the state boundaries i.e. split lines by polygon boundaries.

Is there a geoprocessing tool to do this in QGIS? I can't merge the lines by the way, since they are meaningfully split into tributaries/main river.

Comment: I have tried using vector geometry/ vector overlay / lines intersect tool. This gives me a point layer where lines overlap. However not all overlapping points were found, and I would still prefer if it can be done automatically.

Answer (score 12):

This is now possible by default in QGIS with the ["Intersection"](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectoroverlay.html#intersection) tool.

Comment: The "intersection" tool clips the lines - it removes lines outside the polygon.  This is different from simply splitting, which means cutting lines and including all the resulting parts in the output.

Comment: They are splitting by state, so what interests them is rivers split by individual state. Usually, I would expect that rivers outside of the whole set of polygons are not interesting to them. But good word of warning for those that don't want that!

Answer (score 2):

Intersect didn't work for me in 2.18 or 3x.

To split road lines by zone polygons I used SAGA - Line Polygon intersection that split the line by the polygon

Then the "Attribute Transfer" plugin conflated the attributes across.

Answer (score 2):

I did not have success with the Line-Polygon tool.  I converted my polygon to lines and then used the SAGA->Vector line tools->Split lines with lines.  This worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

In the Processing Toolbox under "Vector Overlay" use the "Split with lines" tool.

Answer (score 0):

It can be done with GRASS.
v.overlay

Comment: Can you add a more detailed description how it can be done with v.overlay?