# Split lines by attributes of overlapping polygon

Tags: qgis-3, split-by-attribute

I have a long line, representing shoreline, with a 3km buffer overtop. The buffer has an attribute field representing the coastal characterisation for a certain length of shoreline, see image.

I am trying to split the line according to the coastal characterisation of the polygon buffer so I can get an accurate distance measure of the actual length of shoreline for each classification category [image: coastal characterisation]

Comment: How about [splitting the line by polygons](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/127066/split-lines-by-polygons-in-qgis)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the intersection tool:

[image]

It has an Overlay function to retrieve data from one layer and add them into another. Just leave it empty, it will add all the field names.

[image]